# Can we find a necessary and sufficient condition to have : $(x^2)^{1-f(x)}+((1-x)^2)^{1-f(1-x)}\leq 1$?

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

It's a possible generalization of an inequality of Vasile Cirtoaje I recall :

> > Let $x,y>0$ such that $x+y=1$ then we have :
> > $$x^{2y}+y^{2x}\leq 1$$

Well the idea is really simple take a function $f(x)$ continuous an differentiable on $I=(0,1)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(0.5)=0.5$ and finally $f(1)=1$ .What conditions make to have :

$$(x^2)^{1-f(x)}+((1-x)^2)^{1-f(1-x)}\leq 1\quad (1)$$

We can put :

$$f(x)=0.5\frac{g(x)}{g(0.5)}$$

Moreover I think it works with increasing functions . Maybe we can add the idea of convexity (?).

I have tested example as $g(x)=\sin(x)$ or $g(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\tanh(x)$ and it seems to work .

My question :

Can we find a necessary and sufficient conditions to have the inequality $(1)$ ?

Thanks in advance !!

### Update :

Let $0<x<1$ then define :

$$h(x)=x^{g(x)}$$

We have as constraints :

$1)$  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)=0$ and $h(0.5)=0.5$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-}h(x)=1$

$2)$  $(h(x))'\geq 0 $ $\forall x\,\operatorname{such that}\, 0<x<1$

$3)$ $g(x)$ is convexe on $(0,1)$

$4)$ $h(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and twice differentiable on this interval

Then define the three functions :

$p(x)=h(x)+h(1-x)$ $\quad$ $q(x)=x^{-g(x)}$ and $f(x)=q(x)+q(1-x)$

And the last constraints :

If $p(x)\leq 1$ then the only equality case is $x=0.5$

$f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and twice differentiable on this interval

Now my conjecture :

$$\forall x \operatorname{such that} 0<x<1 \,, p(x)\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow f(x)\ln(p(x)) \operatorname{is concave on}\,(0,1)$$

As in my answer we can use Jensen's inequality to prove one of the logical implications .

For the other we can use the definition of the log concavity :

$$(r'(x))^2\geq r''(x)r(x)$$

In the fact there is two big blocks  which cancel each other out .Remains a part of the second derivative  that I cannot study .

Any helps or initiatives would be very appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;h(x):\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}\;$ be the function defined as

$h(x)=\left(x^2\right)^{1-f\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{2}\;\;\;\;$ for all $\;x\in\left[0,1\right],$

where $f(x):\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that

$f(0)=0$, $\;\;\;f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$, $\;\;\;f(1)=1$.

It results that

$h(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$, $\;\;\;h\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$, $\;\;\;h(1)=\frac{1}{2}$,

$h(x)>-\frac{1}{2}\;\;$ for all $\;x\in\left]0,1\right]\;$.

Moreover, the inequality
$$\left(x^2\right)^{1-f(x)}+\left[\left(1-x\right)^2\right]^{1-f(1-x)}\leq 1\quad \color{blue}{(*)}$$
is equivalent to
$$h(x)+h(1-x)\le0.$$

So, if $\;\alpha(x):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is any function such that

$\alpha(1-x)\le -\alpha(x)\;\;\;\forall x\in[0,1]\;,\;$

$\alpha(x)>-\frac{1}{2}\;\;$ for all $\;x\in\left]0,1\right]\;\;$ and

$\alpha(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$, $\;\;\;\alpha\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$, $\;\;\;\alpha(1)=\frac{1}{2}\;$,

then the function

$f(x)= \begin{cases}
  1-\frac{\ln\left[\alpha(x)+\frac{1}{2}\right]}{2\ln x}\;\;\;\;\text{ for all } x\in\left]0,1\right[\\
  0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{ for } x=0\\
  1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{ for } x=1
\end{cases}$

satisfies the inequality $(*)$ for all $x\in\left[0,1\right]$ and

$f(0)=0$, $\;\;\;f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$, $\;\;\;f(1)=1$.

Conversely, if $f(x):\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function which satisfies the inequality $(*)$ for all $x\in\left[0,1\right]$ and

$f(0)=0$, $\;\;\;f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$, $\;\;\;f(1)=1$,

then there exists a function $\;\alpha(x):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\;$ such that

$\alpha(1-x)\le -\alpha(x)\;\;\;\forall x\in[0,1]\;,\;$

$\alpha(x)>-\frac{1}{2}\;\;$ for all $\;x\in\left]0,1\right]\;,\;$

$\alpha(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$, $\;\;\;\alpha\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$, $\;\;\;\alpha(1)=\frac{1}{2}\;$ and

$f(x)= \begin{cases}
  1-\frac{\ln\left[\alpha(x)+\frac{1}{2}\right]}{2\ln x}\;\;\;\;\text{ for all } x\in\left]0,1\right[\\
  0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{ for } x=0\\
  1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{ for } x=1
\end{cases}$

Comment: Well it looks fine even if I think we cannot prove the inequality of Vasile Cirtoaje with that .It's a theoretical example with no application .It seems moreover a little bit tautological. Anyway . (+1)

Comment: I have just obtained a necessary and sufficient condition so that the inequality $(*)$ is satisfied as you asked. Moreover, I think that it is not a little bit tautological, indeed solving $$h(x)+h(1-x)\le0$$ is much easier than solving $(*)$. Next days I will solve $h(x)+h(1-x)\le0$.

Comment: Yes you're right but the example itself seems tautological because we haven't really information on it (like increase or convex)  .Yes it's necessary and sufficient and I don't  expect that.I don't critisize you I critisize the reality of this fact wich is really not satisfactoring .   That's why I think you said :Next days I will solve ...Correct me if I'm wrong.Thanks Angelo !

Comment: What do you mean when you say “tautological”? If you mean redundant, uselessly repeated, etc, I am sorry but I think that I got a necessary and sufficient condition which allow us to find all the functions that satisfy your inequality. I wrote all the functions that satisfy your inequality through the solutions of a much easier inequality that is $h(x)+h(1-x)\le0$.

Comment: No i mean more something wich doesn't gives really good informations.Anyway   the task is big .Good sleep:-)

Comment: I do not think that all the functions that satisfy your inequality, also satisfy the same conditions such as increasing, convexity, etc. If you want a necessary and sufficient condition, I think it is not possible to get something explicit as you want.

Comment: I think that it is good information to know how to get all the functions that satisfy your inequality through the solutions of a much easier inequality which is $h(x)+h(1-x)\le0$. I worked  with your question for hours and I do not think I have only obtained something tautalogical. I have done a constructive proof about how to get all the functions that satisfy your inequality. So far I am the only person who has worked to answer your question.

Comment: Yes I think the same now .Thanks for the help !